# Error on line 55, column 4 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping. fonts:

Tags: flutter-dependencies

Error on line 55, column 4 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
   fonts:

Comment: You didn't post any files/example of the files causing an error. We can't help you without information, please add more details. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

fonts:
    - family: Heebo
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Heebo-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Heebo-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: fonts/Heebo-Black.ttf
          weight: 400

there is requre two spaces in between fonts and family

Answer (score 0):

1.In Android Studio, you need to create a package under lib folder. For example you create a package fonts (path is app_name/lib/fonts).

2.In the pubspec.yaml the code would look like:

```
flutter:
    fonts:
      - family: Oxygen
        fonts:
          - asset: app_widgets/lib/fonts/Oxygen-Regular.ttf
          - asset: app_widgets/lib/fonts/Oxygen-Bold.ttf
            weight: 700
          - asset: app_widgets/lib/fonts/Oxygen-Light.ttf
            weight: 300
```